# how to stop links in media from going to other websites

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to know how you can stop links from happening in media to go to other websites. These include modified flash files in movies and images etc. I would like to know how you can stop it from happening so when I go to my website and click the object it will not open a new tab and go to there website.

Comment: Could you show an example of such a piece of code to work a solution? Also, have you even tried anything? As this is completely do-able via jQuery for most DOM-based link elements.

Comment: I'm unclear why you want this... you want links that are for other sites... not to go to other sites?

Comment: Don't put them on your website?